# Can't connect to the apps using android emulator but can connect using device?

Tags: android

I have an open internet connection but I can't connect to a webservice through android emulator...But can connect it to the android device. I want to connect it through emulator for my daily work, is it possible through wi-fi? Why it's not connected?

Comment: Are you by any chance behind a firewall that might be blocking the emulator? Can you connect to other URLs from your emulator?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code using Log . it will help you to identify how and where it is failing.

Comment: yes can connect to other urls only through this url can't login my app..

Comment: how to debug the code, i'm a beginner in android.plz explain